# PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: nxt in...

Tags: php

Как исправить ошибки:

> `PHP Notice: Undefined variable: nxt in /var/www/user/data/www/localhost/phpscript/index.php on line 222, referer: http://localhost/phpscript/ 
> PHP Notice: Undefined variable: nxt in /var/www/user/data/www/localhost/phpscript/index.php on line 213, referer: http://localhost/phpscript/ 
> PHP Notice: Undefined variable: nxt in /var/www/user/data/www/localhost/phpscript/index.php on line 237, referer: http://localhost/phpscript/`

Код начиная со строки 211 и заканчивая 242 строкой:

```
}else{ 
if(($i<1)||($nxt>0)){ 
$word[$i]=ucfirst($word[$i]); 
$last=ucfirst($last); 
$nxt=0; 
} 
} 
} 
}else{ 
if(($i<1)||($nxt>0)){ 
$word[$i]=ucfirst($word[$i]); 
$last=ucfirst($last); 
$nxt=0; 
} 
} 
}else{ 
if(($i<1)||($nxt>0)){ 
$word[$i]=ucfirst($word[$i]); 
$last=ucfirst($last); 
$nxt=0; 
} 
} 
}else{ 
if($word[$i]!="&br&"){ 
if($word[$i]!=""&"){ 
$word[$i]=str_replace("&", "", $word[$i]); 
$word[$i]=str_replace("**", ". ", $word[$i]); 
$word[$i]=str_replace("*", ", ", $word[$i]); 
$part=explode("=", $word[$i]); 
$part1=str_replace("|", " ", $part[0]); 
$part2=str_replace("|", " ", $part[1]); 
$change="есть!";
```

Где здесь ошибки, как исправить ошибки?

Comment: Не ну это пик лени и неуважения...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто вставьте `$nxt=0;` в самое начало скрипта и проблема исчезнет :)

Comment: Теперь начала возникать такая ошибка: PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 0 in [путь до файла] 190 line.
Строка 188 - 196: <code>}else{
   if($word[$i][0]!="&" and $word[$i][count($word[$i])-1]!="&"){
    if(strlen($last)>3){ //Если слово больше 3х символов и нету в списке плохих слов, пытаемся синонимизировать
     $n_sl--;
     if(!in_array($last,$bad_word)){
      if($n_sl<1){
       $pos=0;
       preg_match('/
'.$last.'\|(.*)/', $all, $match);</code>